# html.Div style problem. Cant adjust position on page for my slider

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I can adjust the width of my slider (and all other html.Divs) but that only adjusts how far east it goes on my screen. I cant adjust the starting position, therefore instead of my first point beeing 1950, it looks like its 50. (the 19 is not on the screen)

Using dash_html_components and dash_core_components in python, and cant code CSS or Html

**My code:**

```
html.Div(
    [    
        dcc.Slider(
            id='year-slider',
            min=df['year'].min(),
            max=df['year'].max(),
            value=df['year'].min(),
            marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['year'].unique()},
            step=None,
        )
    ], 
    style= {'width': '90%'} 
)
```

Comment: A screenshot of the view could help understand better.

Comment: Will add this next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly adding a style to the div
, style= {'width': '90%', 'display': 'block', 'margin-left': '5%';} )